# Nested Python deafultdict performance

Tags: python-3.x

I have a huge spark matrix that is represented in python as nested defaultdict named H. (`H` has 107456 vertices and 882640 edges).
It is required in the homework to multiply this matrix with a vector `x_keyed` (`V_names` is the vertices names).

```
x_keyed = vector_keyed (keys=[v for v in V_names], values=1.)

def spmv_keyed(A, x):

    y = vector_keyed(keys=A.keys(), values=0.0)
    for i in y.keys():
        #s=0
        for j in y.keys():
            if i in A and j in A[i]:
                #print(A[i][j], "*", x[j])
                y[i]+=A[i][j]*x[j]
return y

%timeit spmv_keyed (H, x_keyed)
```

When I call the function `spmv_keyed (H, x_keyed)`, it never comes back. Any suggestions for speeding this up?

Comment: Looks like there might be a few typos in the code. Can you double-check and fix if necessary?

Comment: You might consider switching to something like `networkx` that has optimized implementations of common graph operations, or `numpy` which has optimized matrix implementations.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, it's required it the assignment to be coded with primitive python

Comment: @ScottSkiles, I use Jupyter notebook, the code runs correctly when I limit the number of iteration in the loop to 10000, more than 10000 the kernel timeout. it's not syntax problem, it's a logic problem

Comment: @Reem - This is what I'm referring to: `x_keyed = vector_keyed (keys=[v for v in V_names], values=1.)`. 
I was not sure if this ran or not. I'm not saying it is a syntax problem. I agree is is a performance issue. Your code is O(n^2), so with large input sizes it will not finish in a reasonable amount of time. I just edited your Q but did not have time to answer. Good luck!